# What is this pattern ~겠다 하여라?

Tags: grammar

"사고에게 맡기겠다 하여라"
사고 is a person.
I know that ~다가 gets shortened to ~다 but in this case it doesn't make sense. 
Can anyone explain what this means?
Context: Person 1 is taking to person 2 and 사고 is the third person.

Comment: In this case, ~다 is a shortened form of ~다고, not ~다가.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jungyh0218 says, 다 here is a shortened form of ~다고 - a quotational.

하여라 makes the sentence an imperative (with the tone of talking down to someone).

So the meaning is "Say that I will leave it up to Sago", or "Tell Sago I will leave it up to him/her", depending on context.

A similar sentence, but more polite in tone, would be 사고에게 맡기겠다고 해주세요.

So **~겠다 하여라** is an instruction to **say that (something) will happen**.